# Rolling regression forecast , DM test, CW test

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, currency-exchange-rates

I have a linear model with the exchange rate as a dependent variable and 7 others independent variables(e.g. inflation, interest  rate etc.). I have quarterly data from 1993Q1-2011Q4. 
I would like to create a rolling window regression (with the model above) with window size 60(from 1993Q1-2007Q4) and use the estimated regression to forecast the rest sample. Also, I would like to compare this model with the Random Walk model(exchange rate follows a R.W.). In the end, I would like to perform the dm.test and clarkwest test(does not run). Is my code right?

```
X = embed(data)
X = as.data.frame(X)

install.packages("foreach")
library(foreach)
w_size=60
n_windows = nrow(X) - 60 #until 2007Q4
forecasts = foreach(i=1:n_windows, .combine = rbind) %do%{
    # = Select data for the window (in and out-of-sample) = #
  X_in = X[i:(w_size + i - 1), ] # = change to X[1:(w_size + i - 1), ] for expanding window
  X_out = X[w_size + i, ]

  # = Regression Model = #
  m1 = lm(V1 ~ V2+V3+V4+V5+V6+V7+V8, data = X_in)
  f1 = predict(m1, X_out)

  # = Random Walk = #
  f2 = tail(X_in$V1, 1)

  return(c(f1, f2))
}
 e1 = tail(X[ ,"V1"], nrow(forecasts)) - forecasts[ ,1]
 e2 = tail(X[ ,"V1"], nrow(forecasts)) - forecasts[ ,2]
library(tseries)     
library(forecast)
dm.test(e1,e2, "l") #p-value is more than 5% for all the cases( two.sided, greater, less)
clarkwest(e1,e2)
```

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding what you're asking - can you clarify what part of your code isn't working?

Comment: Hello Evan,
My code works fine until the clarkwest(e1,e2) command(which probably R does not support). However, it is more essential for me to know if my code before this command is right. I am not keen on R, so what I am asking is if this is how we create a rolling regression based on which we forecast.
My code follows this article : https://www.r-bloggers.com/formal-ways-to-compare-forecasting-models-rolling-windows/

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the `clarkwest()` function is not supported anymore. I recently wrote my own function: [CW](https://github.com/martinbaumgaertner/Clarkwest) Note that I used normal standard errors and not Newey-West corrected.

To investigate your loop you could try:

```
i=1
X_in = X[i:(w_size + i - 1), ] # = change to X[1:(w_size + i - 1), ] for expanding window
X_out = X[w_size + i, ]

# = Regression Model = #
m1 = lm(V1 ~ V2+V3+V4+V5+V6+V7+V8, data = X_in)
f1 = predict(m1, X_out)

# = Random Walk = #
f2 = tail(X_in$V1, 1)
```

Here you can see the composition the loop creates when i=1

Comment: Hello, 
Do you know if my code for out-of-sample prediction is right(before clarkwest() command)? Could you suggest me anything else? I follow this article: https://www.r-bloggers.com/formal-ways-to-compare-forecasting-models-rolling-windows/

Comment: The code looks okay to me. But it is always a good idea to test it. You could check the outcomes in detail for some values i. (e.g. i=1, 10, 30)

Comment: Thank you for the response. Whole sample has 75 observations after some alterations. Following this code, when I type to show "X_in" it shows that it takes values from observation 15 to 74. Shouldn't it include the first 1 to 60 observations, since I want e.g. to estimate the model with the first 60 observations to forecast the obsevation 61? Also when I type to show "X_out" it shows the values of obsevation 75(last observation).

Comment: It seems okay to me. It seems that you just exucuted the hole loop in one piece. You are looping from i to n.windows. n. windows should be 75-60=15. So you first you set i=1, then i=2 etc.. in the last step you will have i=15.  See my edit in my comment.

Comment: I see. Instead of forming the random walk model with this code above: 
f2 = tail(X_in$V1, 1)
I created the random walk model with this code:
 m2 = lm(V1 ~ 1, data= X_in) #random walk with drift
  f2 = predict(m2, X_out)
Which one do you think is more suitable? Consider that I want to compare my model with the random walk model with drift.

Comment: If you want to include a drift you could compare your result with the `forecast` package. The command `rwf(X_in,h=1,drift=TRUE)$mean` to crosscheck it.